# Verifying search filtering in Ruby Selenium Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm very new to Ruby, Selenium, and UI automation, and have a quick question on how to get a count of visible items in a drop down menu.

Example: I have a drop down menu of 10 currency values (USD, EUR, JPN, etc.). They're coded as:

```
<div class="list_item">Currency Symbol</div>
```

The drop down menu is searchable, and if I type in "**USD**", then the only visible item would be that particular currency value. All other div of that class get a `style="display: none;"` attribute. How do I verify that that **USD** indeed is the only item in the menu? An example of such a situation can be seen here: https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/

Conceptually, I was thinking of doing this:

1. Iterate through each `div` tag with `class=List_item`, and if I find one that has a display, count it. Then verify if it equals to '1'.

I tried using `find_elements` but can't seem to find attribute within each element in the array (is it because they aren't webdriver objects?).

If there's another better approach, it'd be really good to know and learn more as well. Appreciate any responses.

Comment: Do you have any more code?

Comment: It would help if share the HTML for a complete list, which has some items visible and some that are not.

Comment: Sure! The specific page I was looking at for practice is here: https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in this particular example, you could do

```
@driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//div[@class='currency_dropdown']/div[@id='scroll-innerBox-1']/div[not(@style='display: none;')]").size
```

This should return 1 when USD is typed into the search field.

Edit: I recommend getting ChroPath for your preferred browser (FF or Chrome). It helps significantly when testing xpath.